# Cartesian form of vectors

Tags: vectors

With respect to the origin O, the points A, B, C, D have position vectors given by $$ \overrightarrow {OA} = \mathbf i  + 3\mathbf j + \mathbf k  $$

$$\overrightarrow {OB} = \mathbf 2i  + \mathbf j - \mathbf k$$

$$\overrightarrow {OC} = \mathbf 2i  + 4\mathbf j + \mathbf k$$

$$\overrightarrow {OD} = \mathbf 3i  + \mathbf j + 2\mathbf k$$

$(i) $Find the equation of the plane containing A, B and C, giving your answer in the form $ax + by + cz = d$

How do I tackle these type of questions?

Comment: Hint: Find the vectors AB and AC. Those will generate the plane you want

Answer (score 0):

The plane containing $A,B,C$

Point $D$ is irrelevant.

First find two vectors in the plane:

$\vec {AB} = 1\mathbf i - 2\mathbf j -  2\mathbf k\\
\vec {AC} = 1\mathbf i + 1\mathbf j$

I prefer the $(1,-2,-2), (1,1,0)$ notation to the $\mathbf i,\mathbf j,\mathbf k$ notation.

Now we need to find a vector that is perpendicular to those two (normal to the plane).  The cross product is the most "mechanical" and reliable way to do this, but is not necessarily the easiest.

$(2,-2,3)$

$2x -2y + 3z = d$
now plug any of the points for $A,B,$ or $C$ to solve for $d.$

$2x -2y + 3z = -1$

Comment: Sorry, how did you get (2, -2, 3)?

Comment: If the vector is of the from $(a,-a,b)$ it will be orthogonal to $(1,1,0)$  now find $a,b$ such that $a - 2(-a) - 2b = 0 \implies (3a=2b)$  Or, you could take the cross product, as I said above.